# structuring complicated java methods

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, algorithm, architecture

Can anyone show me how to control java's order of execution while still organizing the code in a simplified, easy-to-maintain structure?

I am programming a rather complicated algorithm in java.  One method got to be several hundred lines long, to the point where isolating critical parts of the code for fine tuning the algorithm became too labor-intensive.  To simplify the code, I identified each section of the code that could be resolved to a single variable, and I moved each of those sections to their own methods, which are then called from the formerly complicated method.  This is good, because it makes the code readable, and much easier to maintain.

The problem is that now I am getting some errors that indicate that the calling method is continuing to execute subsequent code before some of the earlier methods have returned their values.

Here is an example in code:

```
void myMethod(Double numb){  
    double first = new getFirst(numb);  
    double second = new getSecond(numb);  
    double third = new getThird(numb);  
    double anAside = new getAnAside(first, second, third);  
    double fourth = new getFourth(numb);  
}
```

The error messages that come up have to do with things happening in `getFourth(numb)` at the same time when I am getting `System.out.println()` results in the eclipse console indicating that `getFirst(numb)` is still running.  Back when I had all the contents of `getFirst(numb)`, `getSecond(numb)`, `getThird(numb)`, `getAnAside(first,second,third)`, and `getFourth(numb)` within `myMethod(numb)`, I was not getting the same evidence that code blocks were running out of order.  (Because their were no sub-methods, the code was all in one long block.)  However, the code was difficult to read.  How can I make changes to `myMethod(numb)` above so that each method must be fully returned before moving on to the next, so that I can still have easy to read code?

Comment: "indicate that the calling method is continuing to execute subsequent code before some of the earlier methods have returned their values" Assuming that you have one thread running this code, this is not possible. Your logging might be buggy, or maybe you have methods used by both `getFourth` and getFirst` being called but are identified in logs as `fourth` only?

Comment: This is a bit of guesswork, but I have known IDEs to display stdout output in the wrong order.  I suggest you eliminate this first (even if it is unlikely), either by running Java from a proper terminal or writing the logs to disk.

Comment: why are you concerned about the order they run in?

Comment: @Mike `first`, `second`, `thrid` necessary for `anAside`. Plus, its an example

Comment: Possibly you need modifier [`volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java)? if you have parallel methods access variables that tend to change constantly, and the compiler tries to optimize, it could throw errors, (I think).

Comment: @SGM1 the only hard requirement I see is that `First`, `Second` and `Third` must run before `anAside`. they can run in any order and `four` is completely independent. Still, why does the order mater

Comment: "If it looks complicated, it is complicated. If it is complicated, it is wrong."

Comment: @CodeMed A method containing several hundred lines of code is _always wrong_, as it horribly ignores encapsulation and other fundamental programming techniques. It does not matter, whether it calculates the right result. It will be unmaintainable after short time, because reading/understanding/maintaining code is the important part in developing, not writing it in the first place. I suggest diving into the "needs milk" answer and reading a bit about top-down development maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of guesswork, but I have known IDEs to display stdout output in the wrong order. I suggest you eliminate this first (even if it is unlikely), either by running Java from a proper terminal or writing the logs to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing your System.out between each method like this:

```
void myMethod(Double numb)
{  
    double first = new getFirst(numb);
    System.out.flush();
    double second = new getSecond(numb);
    System.out.flush();
    double third = new getThird(numb);
    System.out.flush();
    double anAside = new getAnAside(first, second, third);
    System.out.flush();
    double fourth = new getFourth(numb);  
}
```

As Matt B mentions, if you are only using one thread then it is probably something faulty with your logging.

Answer (score 1):

I usually find that in terms of program structure, algorithms are never as complicated as people make them out to be. All you have to do is talk it out and write as you go. Say my fridge needs milk so that I need an algorithm to go get milk in the store:

```
public Milk goGetMilk(){
    getMoney();
    getCarKey();
    driveToStore();
    findMilk();
    buyMilk();
    driveBack();
    putMilkInFridge();
}
```

Then each nested method can in turn be broken into chuncks until I have a complete program.

As far as order of execution goes, if you have one thread: it's impossible to have racing conditions. If you are using multiple threads, you need to synchronize shared resources and rendezvous points.